# how to render DataTemplate in UI

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone, datatemplate

In .NET/WP/WPF, I am looking to create my first user control that will render content using a DataTemplate and am wondering how to do that. Do I need to use the Content presenter and pass it a reference to the template or what? Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Make sure to check the difference between `ContentPresenter` and `ContentControl`. Generally, if the `Content` is going to change, use `ContentControl`. If it will not change, use `ContentPresenter`.

Comment: @Nate - I'm curious what your thinking is behind that recommendation. There's no difference in the binding updates of the two other than the default ContentControl template passing all of the data through to a ContentPresenter for actual display.

Comment: In my experience once a content presenter has bound to content (and retrieved a content template), it will not change templates on update to the Content (assuming you use a ContentTemplateSelector), whereas ContentControl does this automatically. It may be that there is a setting that I am simply missing somewhere, but this has been my experience with it so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic strategy for including templated content in other fixed content (like the XAML of a `UserControl`) is to define a set of `Content` properties (as `DependencyProperties`) on the containing control and then add a `ContentPresenter` (with appropriate bindings) as the placeholder into which the content will be injected. In the framework you can see an example of this in `HeaderedContentControl` which has both a normal `Content` property set, but also a parallel set of `Header` properties that are used as a second piece of content.

The properties you can define on your control (differing by platform) are:

- `Content`
- `ContentTemplate`
- `ContentTemplateSelector`
- `ContentStringFormat`

with whatever your custom name is substituted for "Content" in each. In your case you probably only have the first two. Then in your `UserControl` layout (which is actually defining the Content itself of the `UserControl`) just place a `ContentPresenter` and set it up to use your custom properties with the control itself as the `Binding Source` (`ElementName`, `RelativeSource`, or setting the `DataContext` somewhere to the `UserControl` itself):

```
 <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=MyExtraContent}"
                   ContentTemplate="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=MyExtraContentTemplate}" />
```

In most cases (but not here) `ContentPresenter` is used inside a `ControlTemplate` where you can use a nice shortcut that's built in to bind all the content properties for you:

```
<ContentPresenter ContentSource="MyExtraContent"/>
```

You can get the same effect with `ContentControl` but it's adding extra elements to your visual tree since it's basically just a `ContentTemplate` containing a `ContentPresenter` that passes all the properties through. It does allow you to add some visual differences, like `Background` or `Padding`, or add a whole custom template but in cases like this you can do exactly the same thing by just adding other controls around your `ContentPresenter`.